# How to prevent NFT or Enjin Token copying?

Tags: ether, etherscan, nft

So lets say someone mints an Enjin token pointing to a 3D model asset for a game.

What prevents someone from downloading that same exact 3D model, and minting a new token that points to it?

Are the contents of an NFT hidden to others until they purchase them? I was looking at ethereum chain explorer for an NFT here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e

I do not see any links to a jpeg file. Is there a way to actually see that information?

Comment: whats the difference between ERC-721 and Enjin token?

Comment: enjin token runs on ERC-1155

Comment: Everything on the blockchain is public. You cannot prevent anyone from copying a token. Although the blockchain can be used to show you created it early.